# Moving the files to done folder after ETL process is done in Talend

Tags: database, etl, talend

I need to move the files after they went through the ETL process into a done folder. However, since they are now placed inside a (working directory), when they are done and I move them to "done" directory, I keep on getting null errors, since I believe the file watcher is still looking inside the (working director)

I need a way to allow me to move the files after they get processed in ETL into another folder, without having problem with file watcher

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tFileCopy component to move the files. I am attaching a sample Document Flow and the details of the tFileCopy.

[image]